# evaluate the space required for backup

Tags: 14.04, backup

How do I evaluate how much space is necessary to store backup in my ubuntu system ?

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32bit)

Answer (score 0):

Depending if you want to backup an entire partition/disk or only some directories first get the size:

Entire parition/disk (replace sda1 with your disk/partition):

```
df -h /dev/sda1
```

(h means human readable, see `man df` for details and options)

Directory only:

```
du -sh
```

(s means sum up, h means human readable, see `man du` for details)

With this you get the size of the stuff you want to backup. The next step depends on your backup software. If it uses a compression, you can guess the compressed size by multiplying the size with the average compression ratio.